# consistent colors after multiple calls of pd.DataFrame.plot()

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, colors

I have a dataframe `v` with some numerical data in it.

```
v=pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(300,3))
```

I am want to plot on the same `matplotlib` figure:

- a scatter plot
- a moving average of the same points

I do that using `pd.DataFrame.plot()`

```
plt.figure()
v.plot(style='o',legend=False,ax=plt.gca(),alpha=0.2,ls='')
v.rolling(7).mean().plot(legend=False,ax=plt.gca())
```

This works fine.

However, the points drawn with the first plot are colored according to their row number. Same happens for the lines in the second plot.

I would like the two colors to be consistent between the two plot commands, so 
line obtained by moving average to have same color as in the scatter. How to get that?

Here is what I get running the code.
Obviously, I cannot figure out if the red lines correspond to the green orange or blue points...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ORIGINAL**

I believe you need -

```
%matplotlib inline # only for jupyter notebooks
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

colors = {0: 'red', 1:'green', 2:'blue'}
v=pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(300,3))
plt.figure()
v.plot(marker='o',legend=False,ax=plt.gca(),ls='', alpha=0.2, color=colors.values())
v.rolling(7).mean().plot(legend=False,ax=plt.gca(), color=colors.values())
```

**UPDATE**

Just go with -

**Option 1 (no extra `cm` dependency)**

```
colors_rand = np.random.rand(len(v.columns),3)
v.plot(marker='o',legend=False,ax=plt.gca(),ls='', alpha=0.5, color=colors_rand )
    v.rolling(7).mean().plot(legend=False,ax=plt.gca(), color=colors_rand )
```

**Option 2(as suggested by OP)**

```
v.plot(marker='o',legend=False,ax=plt.gca(),ls='', alpha=0.5, colors=cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0,1,v.shape[1]) ))
v.rolling(7).mean().plot(legend=False,ax=plt.gca(), colors=cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0,1,v.shape[1]) ))
```

Comment: could you make it more general by adding that colors can be generated as colors=cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0,1,v.shape[1]))

Comment: just one remark. In option 1, you probably need to ''freeze' the colors used produced by the first call to random in order to use them again